# Apply small caps to a text in java swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have the following code:

```
  headerLabel.setText("TEST APPLICATION DATA");
```

//    headerLabel.setFont(new Font("",Font.ITALIC,25));
     headerLabel.setFont(new Font("Century Schoolbook L",Font.BOLD,22));

THe font that is required is Century SchoolBook and I want the first letter of each word to be bigger in size than other letters of the word. All letters in capitals but first letter of each word should have bigger size than other letters .

How should I apply this?

Comment: You can't do this the way you are now, the font is applied to the entire text

Comment: Perhaps you can open up photoshop or some other kind of software...design the letters the way you want, then save it as a picture. Afterwards, add the picture to your GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

So you wound need to wrap the text in HTML. The first letter would use a different font size than the remaining letters.

Edit:

Something like:

```
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("<html><font size=\"25\">T</font>EST APPLICATION DATA</html>");
label2.setFont(new Font("Century Schoolbook L" ,Font.BOLD ,22));
```

Edit 2:

Another option is to use a customized JTextPane (so that it looks like a JLabel. Then you can apply different Fonts to the text. The benefit of this approach is that when you don't need to parse the text to build the HTML String and when you use the `getText()` method you will get the text, not the formatted string.

Comment: I am reading through it. BUt will it apply CenturySchoolBook font?

Comment: camickr:
I had tried wrapping up the text string in html but it is not applying the style font-variant:small caps

Comment: Hey it worked. I used simple font tag and the result is geting dsiplayed. Thanks!! I have acceptd your answer. But one problem I had earlier is that I was using <style> tag and it wasnt applying font-variant:small-caps property.. with <font> tag it works now

Comment: @user2822187, Beat me to it, I was just in the process of adding an example.

Comment: U can put it so that it can help other people if they are looking for same

Comment: DO chek my blog I have provided in my profile in case ur interested ;)